# Divisor sum property of Euler phi function with Mobius inversion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function, mobius-function

I have the following formula of the Mobius inversion:

$$g(n) = \sum_{d|n}f(d) \iff f(n) = \sum_{d|n}g(\frac{n}{d})\mu(d)$$

The euler phi function has a divisor sum property: $\sum_{d|n}\phi(\frac{n}{d}) = \sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$

As I understand it:

In this case $f = g = \phi$ and $\mu(d) = 1 \,\text{for }\forall d$.

Are my assumptions correct(is the above understanding of the connection of Euler phi and Mobius correct)?

Why is $\mu(d) = 1$ if my assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the property for Euler's totient function we just use that the divisors $d$ are in bijection with the codivisors $n/d$, so that
$$\sum_{d|n}\phi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = \sum_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$$
This is also called [Sum Over Divisors Equals Sum Over Quotients](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_Over_Divisors_Equals_Sum_Over_Quotients).

However, the Moebius inversion formula, for $f(n)=\phi(n)$ gives  $g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=n$, and not $g(n)=\phi(n)$. So this is impossible.

Comment: So basically I don't even have to know the Mobius function to prove this.

Comment: Yes, you can prove it just by "sum over divisors equals sum over quotients" for the divisor sums.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to prove it with Mobius function ?

Comment: Moebius version formula is a different topic. This is like you would ask to show that $2$ divides $6$ by using the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$.